# Parsing VBA Module function parameters via reflection

Tags: vba, reflection

In Excel, I have a VBA module called `MyModule` which has a function as such

```vb
    Public Function MyFunction(Param1 As Range, Param2 As Range) As String
            ' some implementation
    End Function
```

At runtime, I know that I have a module called `MyModule` and I know I have a function called `MyFunction` but I want to inspect dynamically the parameter names `Param1` and `Param2`

In my world (C#), this is called reflection. Can I use similar concepts here to get the parameter name or am I expecting too much from VBA?

Comment: `yourWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("MyModule").CodeModule` should give you access to what you need.

Comment: @assylias this is giving me the whole source code, which is not great, but could help solving my problem. Are you aware of one that can give me the function as an object (similar to C# or JavaScript)?

Comment: I only posted it as a comment because it lacks details, but thinking it would help you get started. I'm sure somebody will post a better answer later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a good analysis at this CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/164036/Reflection-in-VBA-a-CreateObject-function-for-VBA

*Extract:*

> VBA does not support reflection, an OOP concept which has many
>   facets, including the ability to instantiate a class without knowing
>   its type at design time. Reflection offers great flexibility that is
>   agonizingly absent from VBA (at least for those of us who like to use
>   VBA for more than it is typically intended).

There are some reflection-like things possible:

**Example**

For example, if I wanted to create an instance of an Excel Application object without having to declare the type explicitly in code (using Set xlApp = New Excel.Application), I can do so using the following reflection-level object creation code:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application 
Set xlApp = CreateObject(,"Excel.Application")
```

This is the equivalent of the type specific statement

```
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
```

**Also:**

You can use [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) approach to interrogate your own code (using regexp or some other parsing to pick out the parts of your code you are interested in):

```
yourWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("MyModule").CodeModule
```

There are some interesting leads in this post: [Iterating through the Object Browser in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892039/iterating-through-the-object-browser-in-vba)

Comment: Is it also possible to get private members (like properties) of a class module instance somehow?