# How to return name of parameter in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, reflection, parameters

Does anyone have an idea how to return parameter name in VBA?

This is what I have:

```
Sub Main()
Dim MyString As String
MyString = "Hello World"
MsgBox MyString
End Sub
```

It shows only "Hello World". I would like to have it "MyString says Hello World", but dynamically, not by entering

```
MsgBox "MyString says " & MyString
```

I would prefer something like

```
MsgBox ParamName(MyString) & " says " & MyString
```

but it actually won't work... Could anyone help?

Comment: Put simply, you can't - VBA doesn't support this.

Comment: VBA doesn't support any sort of reflection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing VBA Module function parameters via reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200535/parsing-vba-module-function-parameters-via-reflection)

Comment: Someday I'm going to blow through all of the vba + reflection questions and give answers to them all. Mark my words. I'll make it possible.

Comment: @RubberDuck Hello, so did you find a way, 7 years later :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909192/how-to-iterate-through-the-members-of-a-standard-module

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have accomplished what you are looking to do here. However, please note that this will currently only work for your first parameter in a macro assigned to a Form control:

**Step 1**

Add the following code, adapted from [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm), to a new Module:

```
Public Function ExportModules(ModuleName As String) As String
    Dim bExport As Boolean
    Dim wkbSource As Excel.Workbook
    Dim szSourceWorkbook As String
    Dim szExportPath As String
    Dim szFileName As String
    Dim cmpComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent

    ''' The code modules will be exported in a folder named.
    ''' VBAProjectFiles in the Documents folder.
    ''' The code below create this folder if it not exist
    ''' or delete all files in the folder if it exist.
    If FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Export Folder not exist"
        Exit Function
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Kill FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\*.*"
    On Error GoTo 0

    ''' NOTE: This workbook must be open in Excel.
    szSourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set wkbSource = Application.Workbooks(szSourceWorkbook)

    If wkbSource.VBProject.Protection = 1 Then
    MsgBox "The VBA in this workbook is protected," & _
        "not possible to export the code"
    Exit Function
    End If

    szExportPath = FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\"

    Set cmpComponent = wkbSource.VBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName)

        bExport = True
        szFileName = cmpComponent.Name

        ''' Concatenate the correct filename for export.
        Select Case cmpComponent.Type
            Case vbext_ct_ClassModule
                szFileName = szFileName & ".cls"
            Case vbext_ct_MSForm
                szFileName = szFileName & ".frm"
            Case vbext_ct_StdModule
                szFileName = szFileName & ".bas"
            Case vbext_ct_Document
                ''' This is a worksheet or workbook object.
                ''' Don't try to export.
                bExport = False
        End Select

        If bExport Then
            ''' Export the component to a text file.
            cmpComponent.Export szExportPath & szFileName

        ''' remove it from the project if you want
        '''wkbSource.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove cmpComponent

        End If

    ExportModules = szExportPath & szFileName
End Function

Function FolderWithVBAProjectFiles() As String
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim SpecialPath As String

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    SpecialPath = WshShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")

    If Right(SpecialPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        SpecialPath = SpecialPath & "\"
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles") = False Then
        On Error Resume Next
        MkDir SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles"
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles") = True Then
        FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles"
    Else
        FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error"
    End If

End Function
```

**Step 2**

Add the following code, adapted from answer #7 [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/442252-visual-basic-applications-get-module-name.html), and from [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html), along with my own function, to a new module (it could be the same module as the first if preferred):

```
Public Function MyMacroInfo() As String

Dim MacroName$, SubName$, ModArr As Variant
Dim ModName As Object, strModName$, i&, j&

MacroName = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).OnAction
SubName = Application.Replace(MacroName, 1, Application.Search("!", MacroName), "")
ModArr = Array(0, 1, 2, 3)

For Each ModName In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    For j = LBound(ModArr) To UBound(ModArr)
        i = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        i = ModName.CodeModule.ProcStartLine(SubName, CLng(ModArr(j)))
        Err.Clear
        If i > 0 Then
            strModName = ModName.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next ModName

MyMacroInfo = strModName
End Function

Public Function GetParamName(ModulePath As String) As String

Dim text As String
Dim textline As String
Dim ParamStartLocation As Long
Dim ParamEndLocation As Long
Dim ParamLength As Long
Dim i As Long

Open ModulePath For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop

Close #1

ParamStartLocation = 0
For i = 1 To 3
    ParamStartLocation = InStr(ParamStartLocation + 1, text, "Dim ")
Next i

ParamEndLocation = InStr(ParamStartLocation, text, " As ")
ParamLength = ParamEndLocation - ParamStartLocation

GetParamName = Left(Right(text, Len(text) - ParamStartLocation - 3), ParamLength - 4)

End Function
```

**Step 3**

Change your sub to the following:

```
Sub Main()

'--------Leave this section at the top of your sub---------
Dim strExportedModule As String
Dim strParamName As String

strExportedModule = ExportModules(MyMacroInfo)
strParamName = GetParamName(strExportedModule)
'-----------------Start your code here---------------------

Dim MyString As String

MyString = "Hello World"
MsgBox strParamName & " says " & MyString

End Sub
```

**Step 4**

Assign `Main` to a Form Button.

**Notes**

1. As noted above, this will only get the first parameter that you dimension in the macro assigned to the Form Button. If this is not acceptable, I'll have to take a look at it to see if it can be modified to meet your needs.
2. As Ron de Bruin notes on his site, you'll need to do the following:

> In the VBE Editor set a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic For
>   Applications Extensibility 5.3" and to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
>   and then save the file.
>
> This code will export the module to a folder named "VBAProjectFiles" in your My Documents folder. If you happen to have a folder saved there with the same name (as unlikely as that is), it will delete all the files in that folder.