# How to iterate through the members of a standard module

Tags: excel, vba, reflection, vbide

My goal is to list the procedures exposed by the compiled `VBProject`, as visible in the Excel Macros menu or when typing a cell formula which makes appear availble UDF. A Solution that list any member (`Enum`, `Sub`, `Function`, etc.) of a `CodeModule` or of the full `VBProject` would be ideal.

I am **not** looking for a code parsing solution.

I could find old mentions of a way to do so in VB with the `VBIDE` library, which ( should / used to ) expose a `VBIDE.Member` class (accessible via the `CodeModule.Members` property) with those interesting properties:

```
Member.Name As String
Member.Type As VBIDE.vbext_MemberType
Member.Scope As VBIDE.vbext_Scope
```

Here is a bigger list, probably exhaustive:

```
Bindable
DisplayBind
StandarMethod
Browsable
HelpContextID
StaticCategory
Hidden
Type
Code
Location
Name
UIDefault
Collection
PropertyPage
VBE
DefaultBind
RequestEdit
Description
Scope
```

For a reason I don't understand, I cannot access them via VBA and the `VBIDE` library, they are not even listed as hidden members in the Object Browser.

Is there a way to get them?
Rubberduck (previously known as Mat's Mug here on Stack Overflow) aka Mathieu Guindon suggests it is possible though: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/03/24/a-reflection-on-vba-reflection/

Another idea: how to use Reflection with VBA?
Again, he suggests it is possible: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/04/10/whats-wrong-with-vba/

Note: the Rubberduck COM Add-In that integrates with the VBE, is able to do it (using .NET as I understand it)

Comment: If it's just the procedure names you need, the VBE Extensibility library can indeed be used for that, but it offers no visibility on module-level declarations, which unfortunately includes enums - actual reflection would need an API, which Rubberduck included at one point but it wasn't performant and was quite buggy and ended up discontinued.

Comment: Side note, Rubberduck uses a full-blown lexer+parser and implements Classic-VB scoping rules for name resolution in order to achieve what it does - definitely not something I'd attempt to do in VBA!

Comment: As far as I know the VBIDE library can only get the procedure names parsing the CodeModules, which in my case would not be possible since the VBProject is locked.  That's why I asked for something else that a code parsing solution. Maybe you could provide that API as a standole add-in? :) I checked Github, it is far too complex for me...

Comment: I don't understand your second comment

Comment: what about "Someday I'm going to blow through all of the vba + reflection questions and give answers to them all. Mark my words. I'll make it possible" :)

Comment: "Someday" has not yet arrived.

Comment: TBH I haven't completely ruled out shipping that reflection COM API with Rubberduck again, it's just somewhere in my stack, among the project's website rewrite, getting the Rubberduck3 repo public, a twinBASIC MVVM library for VBA, ...and a thousand other things.

Comment: I understand, as an appetizer, maybe you have found out why the old VB6 `Member` class is not exposed while it is the same library?