# Access the Tag property of an unloaded MS-Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm sort of new to MS-Access & VBA programming. I have developed a multi-user application in MS-Access 2016 and VBA and converted to accdb.

I need to get the value I stored in the Tag property of each form I create. The forms are not loaded, but I need to get the value from a module where a superuser of the application can grant/remove user's access to any particular form. Right now I'm using the form's name instead, but form's name doesn't give the same level of detail that I a can store in the Tag property.

Is there a way I can access/get the Tag property value of an unloaded form?

Comment: Are you confusing "loaded" and "displayed"?

Comment: If an Access form has a code module, you can read its properties like this: `Form_yourFormName.Tag`. If it doesn't, you'll have to open it. But even if all forms have a module, I'm not sure how useful that is, because I don't see how to access these class objects dynamically. -- This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892039/iterating-through-the-object-browser-in-vba

Answer (score 2):

> Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with MS-Access at all.

A form is essentially a class module, and a class module is nothing but a "blueprint" for an *object* - it's a *type*.

When you interact with a form, you're actually interacting with an *instance* of that form - an *object*. This is true even when you don't create the instance yourself (using the `New` keyword), because forms have a special attribute (which you can see if you export the module and view it in your favorite text editor), `VB_PredeclaredId`, which is set to `True` - this makes VBA create a global/default instance for you, an *object* that's named after the *type*.

So when you assign `MyAwesomeForm.Tag`, you're working with the *default instance* - an *object*, not a *type*. This is potentially confusing, because VBA names the object exactly like the type.

Because the instance is global, and managed by VBA, you can do this:

```
MyAwesomeForm.Tag = "ABC"
Unload MyAwesomeForm
Debug.Print MyAwesomeForm.Tag 'should print nothing, but won't crash either
```

Merely accessing the `Tag` property of an unloaded global instance will load the object!

And this takes us to your question:

> *Is there a way I can access/get the Tag property value of an unloaded form?*

Absolutely not. Because you'll load an instance of the form simply by accessing the `Tag` property. And it will be empty, because whatever value you set before was set on *another object* of the same *type*.

`Tag` is an *instance* property: it belongs to an *instance*, not to the form *type*. That means you can have this:

```
MyAwesomeForm.Tag = "123"

Dim form1 As MyAwesomeForm
Set form1 = New MyAwesomeForm
form1.Tag = "ABC"

Dim form2 As MyAwesomeForm
Set form2 = New MyAwesomeForm
form2.Tag = "XYZ"

Debug.Print MyAwesomeForm.Tag 'prints 123
Debug.Print form1.Tag 'prints ABC
Debug.Print form2.Tag 'prints XYZ
```

An object is "loaded" when it's "in memory". An object that isn't in memory, doesn't even exist; so no, you can't read or write a property value to an "unloaded" form.

A form can very well be *loaded* but not *displayed* though. If that's what you meant, then the answer is "yes, absolutely!".